# PySimpleGUI problems with BROWSE_FILES_DELIMITER

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am working on my first GUI project using PySimpleGUI. It is basically meant to be a wizard for importing and reading scanned files. I have each step of the wizard as a new function which is called and opens a new window. My problem is that some of the files I expect to import will contain a semicolon(;) character. This is the delimiter that is used by default to separate files with the FilesBrowse() method. Here is the code below:

```
def import_file():
sg.BROWSE_FILES_DELIMITER = '&&'
layout = [  [sg.T("")],
            [sg.Text("Choose a file: "), sg.Input(key = 'selected_files'), sg.FilesBrowse()],
            [sg.Button('Continue'), sg.Button('Cancel')]    ]

###Building Window
window = sg.Window('Receiver Import Wizard', layout, size=(600,150))

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=='Cancel':
        break
    elif event == "Continue":
        print(values['selected_files'])
```

As you can see, I am attempting to use the BROWSE_FILES_DELIMITER global variable to change the delimiter in the printed value. However, for some reason I can't get this to work. I have also tried changing the delimiter at the very beginning of my file under the import statements, but no matter what it still prints a string with a semicolon delimiter. Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for any advice offered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the default value for the default argument, it's value is assigned when function defined, not when function called.

```py
def FilesBrowse(button_text='Browse', target=(ThisRow, -1),
    file_types=(("ALL Files", "*.*"), ), disabled=False, initial_folder=None,
    tooltip=None, size=(None, None), s=(None, None), auto_size_button=None,
    button_color=None, change_submits=False, enable_events=False, font=None,
    pad=None, key=None, k=None, files_delimiter=";", metadata=None):
```

If you don't specify the value for option `files_delimiter`, it will be always `';'`.

Specified Option `files_delimiter='&&'` of `sg.FilesBrowse` when call it.

```py
sg.FilesBrowse(files_delimiter='&&')
```